# Manipulation of data frame using Group by or Aggregate in R

Tags: r, function, group-by, aggregate, data-manipulation

I would like to create the following table via a current data frame that I have.
My current data frame is as follows

```
ID = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",5), rep("C",4))
NRT = c(3,3,4,5,5,3,3,4,3,3,5,5)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(ID,NRT))
```

| ID | NRT |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 5 |
| C | 5 |

I would like to obtain a table as follows which shows the number of times each number appear for each ID

| ID | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| C | 2 | 0 | 2 |

Thanks all for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is :`table(df)`